# Python 2.7 - Draw on Tkinter Canvas from Different Functions

Tags: python, tkinter, python-2.7

In python, can you draw on the Tkinter Canvas from different functions?

If this is possible, can someone give me a super simple illustration of the syntax structure.

Thanks!

Further explanation of what I'm doing (wondering if this is the correct approach, passing the form to another function:

```
def function1:
    self.root=Tk()
    self.root.title("Form Title")
    cw = 318 # canvas width
    ch = 453 # canvas height
    form = Canvas(self.root, width=cw, height=ch,background="orange")
    drawShapes(form)
    form.pack()


def drawShapes(form):
    form.create_rectangle()
    form.create_arc()
    form.create_unicorns()
```

Comment: By "Canvas", do you mean the Tkinter Canvas?

Comment: DSM - Yes. Sorry.  Edited title and OP for Tkinter clarity

Comment: This question is way too vague -- what you ask is about as fundamental as it gets. Of course, you can write a function that does anything you want, and of course, you can write as many functions as you want. Can you do a better job explaining what it is you don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two different ways for Drawing on the canvas: Tkinter.Canvas and Canvas

```
import Tkinter
c = Tkinter.Canvas()
lineId = c.create_line(1,1,2,2)
```

or

```
import Tkinter
import Canvas
c = Tkinter.Canvas()
line = Canvas.Line(c, 1,1,2,2)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply without the snark.